# Java bundle JRE

Tags: deployment, java

so this program, Launch4J says I can bundle a JRE with my program. Since my program requires Java 7, I can bundle that right? I have one concern, the program size. Is the program going to be like 200mb with the JRE packed? Thanks.

Comment: -1: Why not just try and see? Seems like an obvious direction for own research.

Comment: @millimoose Well I mean the actual JRE folder is like 150mb... Do I need all of that?

Comment: You can well check the java version in your main class and if it does not match your requirement throw error. If there is not java, it's self evident to user that he needs to install java.

Comment: @gotuskar "it's self evident to user that he needs to install java" - you're grossly overestimating the capabilities / willingness of users. If a program fails to start up and gives me manual installation instructions, I'm 95% likely to just delete it and find a less annoying (native) alternative. (Assuming this is a "mass market" application, not something aimed at techies or for internal line-of-business use.)

Comment: Personally, I'd seriously consider using [Java Web Start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/). One of the things it handles is automatically installing an appropriate version of Java if necessary. That said, the sandboxing / need to sign apps might be a problem.

Comment: Does the app. have a GUI?  Are you aware of [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. It will still be some megabytes big.

Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4387414/1850609) and comments:

> For the curious, doing this on my 64bit Windows JRE6 dropped the install from 97.7 MB (19.2 MB 7z compressed) to 89.9 MB (17.9 MB 7z compressed), so about -7%

You can also choose to bundle an [alternate, smaller, JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines).

That being said, bundling is ill-advised and should be only used in extreme circunstances. The better option is to point your user to http://www.java.com, and let them install the most adequate version of Java.

Also, you can bundle a JRE in a installer wizard, not the application itself, which may be an alternative if you don't want to change you app launcher.

Comment: Why exactly is bundling ill-advised?

Comment: 1) It makes you liable for bugs in that JRE, as opposed to Oracle.  2) User no longer gets automatic upgrades with the 'private JRE' 3) It risks polluting the user's system with extra Java versions. 4) It makes the download significantly larger. ..

Comment: 5) Having to build/supply 3 different distributable packages for each version, & the (minor) hassles of directing new users to the correct download.