# How do I reduce the size of the JRE?

Tags: java

I recently tried packaging a [Java app for distribution in the Mac App Store](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html), but discovered that by bundling the default JRE, the app increased its file size by about 138 MB. I would like to reduce the size of the JRE by stripping out components that I don't need (e.g. Corba, JavaFX, XML parsing), thus resulting in a smaller increase when I bundle it into an app.

There are a couple of questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4387266/531762), that give some guidelines about what components to remove, but none that actually describe *how* to go about reducing it. What do I need to do to reduce the size of the JRE? Are there certain tools? Do I just download the source and hack out the classes I don't want? Do I edit my currently installed JRE? I'm not really sure where to begin.

Comment: I don't know the Mac store, but couldn't you just not bundle the JRE?
Most people have it already. Indeed i think it comes on Macs by default

Comment: @Oxinabox Apple stopped including Java in OS X around 2010, so only those who go out and download it have it. Regardless, the Mac App Store requires all apps to be self contained and not require anything not installed by default in OS X, hence why a JRE needs to be bundled into the app (preferably one that doesn't add 138 MB).

Comment: Perhaps have it automatically detect whether a JRE is already installed, and if not then go and download it during your app's installation?

Comment: @Saposhiente Unfortunately, that's not permitted by the Mac App Store rules either. The idea is that the user will download the app and have everything they will ever need to run that app.

Answer (score 2):

I havent tested this myself but after some searching heres what I have found.

The [Packaging a Java App for Distribution on a Mac](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) guide gives you a basic look at how to bundle the app (which it sounds like you got already). From there I followed the [docs for app bundler](https://java.net/downloads/appbundler/appbundler.html), on that page under "runtime" you see you can explicitly include or exclude files/folders from the bundling.

According to their docs

`"By default, only the contents of the jre/ directory will be included with the bundled application. All executable content (i.e. bin/, jre/bin/) is excluded. Additional content can be included or excluded using nested <include> and <exclude> elements, respectively."`

From that I took their sample code and added an exclude statement:

```
<-- Import environment variables -->
<property environment="env"/>

<-- Define the appbundler task -->
<taskdef name="bundleapp" classname="com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask"/>

<-- Create the app bundle -->
<target name="bundle-swingset" depends="package">
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="."
        name="Test"
        displayname="Test"
        identifier="com.oracle.javafx.swing.Test"
        shortversion="1.0"
        applicationCategory="public.app-category.developer-tools"
        mainclassname="com/javafx/main/Main">
    <runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}">
            <exclude name="Java IDL Server Tool" /> <!-- exclude from bundle -->
    </runtime>
    <classpath file="${user.home}/bin/javafx-samples-2.2.0/SwingInterop.jar"/>
        <option value="-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"/>
    </bundleapp>
</target>
```

A full list of optional excludes can be found in the JRE root - `$JAVA_HOME/README.txt`. Do a find for the text `Optional Files and Directories` and you'll be at the header of it. I am looking at the JRE7 installation on my computer, the JRE6 readme didnt seem to have anything in it.

I know this isn't working the example you're looking for but I hope it helps you figure it out.