# How can I reduce the OpenJDK 11 bundled JRE in install4j for Linux packages?

Tags: java, install4j

I'm packaging a Java application for Linux using install4j 7.0.8 and I find that when I include in the package the Oracle OpenJDK 11.0.1 for Linux from here:

https://jdk.java.net/11/

that the JRE that's created using the createbundle program is pretty much the same size as the JDK tar.gz file, about 179 Mb.  But the pre-packaged JREs from ej-technologies are only 45 Mb.  How can I create small JREs for Linux like that?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387266/reducing-size-of-jre#4387414

Comment: @MagnusBull This will only work for JREs up to Java 8, since Java 9 the runtime classes are no longer organized in JAR files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a smaller JRE with [jlink](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jlink.html) and then create a JRE bundle from it.

install4j 8 will include functionality to do this directly in the install4j IDE.

Comment: Hi @ingo, can you point me in the right direction for achieving this with Install4j 8? I've created a runtime image with jlink and I'd like to use that as my JRE and application (they are one, in this case).

Comment: If you used jlink yourself, the procedure for that has not change in install4j. However, you should now define the JRE on General Settings->JRE bundles and install4j will run jlink for you.

Comment: Hi @IngoKegel, I got it to work, thank you. I was missing the 'jdk.pack' module in my generated jlink image.